# Node js if condition is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

I want to initialize global variable with body of json object. But in my code `if` is not being executed instead of `if`, `else` part of code executes, if `console.log(typeof ticker)` I get undefined. What appears to be the problem.

```
var ticker;
request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'xyz'
}, (err, res, body) => {

    if (typeof ticker === undefined) {
        ticker = body;
    } else {

        console.log(ticker)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition will always evaluate to `false`. **[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)** operator returns a `string`. So your `if` condition should be:

```
typeof ticker === 'undefined'
```

or

```
 ticker === undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Marco's answer above is the correct answer. What I'm addressing is the following statement and how you can verify it for yourself:

> if condition is not working properly

You can use the debugger to understand your program. Since you're using node, you can verify this right from the command line.

1. Place a `debugger` statement above the line of code you're interested in. This sets a breakpoint.
2. run `node inspect <filename>`
3. A REPL opens up in the command shell, starting from line 1 of your file. To arrive at your breakpoint, simply type `c` or `cont` into the command line

You're now here:

```
> 3 debugger
  4 if (typeof ticker === undefined) {
  5 ticker = body
debug> _
```

4. You can now run expressions right in the REPL to see how node will evaluate them at runtime:

   ```
   debug> typeof ticker
   'undefined'               // aha, there's our programming error
    debug> typeof ticker === undefined
    false
    debug> typeof ticker === 'undefined'  // it works
    true
   ```
5. To further verify the flow of your program, enter`next` in the REPL to see line-by-line where the program flows.

Optionally, you can utilize chrome's interface to debug:

- run `node --inspect-brk <filename>`
- open chrome to `chrome://inspect`
- click `Open dedicated devTools for node`

Chrome's interface allows you to highlight or hover over variables and expressions to see their value.